# Rules on moving a double hackbut

Tags: pathfinder-1e, firearms

One of my players just built himself a [Double Hackbut](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-descriptions/double-hackbut)

The rules on it are not so much vague as non-existent though.

You need a full round action to set it up - that's clear.

You can "wheel it around", but does that mean just turning it to face other directions or full freedom of movement?

Assuming you can move with it then can you move at full speed? How about double-move and run? Can you 5' step? Can you lift it up a step or do you need to set it up again afterwards? What about a full flight of stairs? What effect does difficult terrain have?

Does anyone have any decent information on RAW or RAI as to how on *insert fantasy land of choice* this thing is supposed to work?

Right now it seems obscene, clearly better than all other firearms. It's also supposed to have some sort of movement limitations to bring it into line - but they are so vague it's impossible to see what they actually are!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"[Wheel about](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/wheel+about)" does not mean "move around" in this context; I understand the confusion because in informal speech those are legitimate words to use to describe moving something with wheels, but that specific phrase has a very specific technical meaning. It means to swivel in place, in this case to aim the hackbut (it doesn't just have to point in one direction). So if you want to move, you have to re-set up. Here's a pic of [a mini of a hackbut with a mount](http://progloriaminiatures.blogspot.com/2010/09/hackbut-is-back-in-stock.html):

[image]

Now, there is such a thing as a double hackbut with an actual wheeled mount - [here's a picture of one](http://www.engerisser.de/Bewaffnung/weapons/Doublehackbut.html) - but that's not what they are talking about here (and that one would move 5' a round at best IMO).

Comment: That's certainly a valid reading. However under the definition you linked there is *"to move, roll, or convey on wheels, casters, etc.: The servants wheel the tables out."*

Comment: Which is why it's a reasonable confusion. But a) in a military, naval, or artillery context it means "turn around" and b) which reading makes the rule make sense? QED.